# Publishing Javascrpt/typescript code coverage to Sonarcloud not working with Azure Pipeline

Tags: code-coverage, sonarcloud

I have set the application to generate the coverage report lcov.info

I am trying to publish coverage report to SonarCloud sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=$(projectPath)/coverage/apps/self-service/lcov.info

Using - task: SonarCloudAnalyze@1 to analyze and - task: SonarCloudPublish@1 to Publish to Sonar Cloud.

I verified the lcov.info it is fine and I have also specified the correct path but, still I am not getting the coverage data in SonarCloud

Comment: Can anyone help me to resolve the issue.